# how to stop a loop with readstate in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to stackoverflow.com, so if the question is not very smart peopl apologies to all.

can someone tell me how do I stop when the counter reaches the "max = 100"?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim max As Integer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    i = 10
    max = 100
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/search?q=a&first=" & i & "&FORM=PERE")
    i += 9
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    If i >= max Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If (WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Then
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.bing.com/search?q=a&first=" & i & "&FORM=PERE")
        i += 9
    End If
End Sub
```

I added "WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted" in DocumentoCompleted event

the loop to run on the browser status

the question is: how can I stop it when it reaches the limit "max"?

http://prntscr.com/3gloi0

Comment: in `DocumentCompleted` check if `i <= Max` before issuing Navigate; else do what you have there

Comment: does not work the loop continues indefinitely

Comment: edit your post to show the current code

Comment: I dont see any change to the code, certainly nothing like what I suggested. If you want it to skip ahead to item 100, (thats not a loop), then as the first line in the `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` **event** add: `If i >= max Then Exit Sub`  since you reset it everytime you click, you should be ok

Comment: work now, thank you! ^^

Comment: Plutonix can you help me with something else? 
I have another problem;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an if statement:

```
i += 9
If (i >= MAX) Then
    i = MAX
    Button1.Enabled = False
End if
```

Its simple and does what you want it to. Since you have the code running on a click, simply disable the button. But as your code is writen, it looks like `i` will be reset to 10 every time you click the button.